# Ruby on Rails - Get max and sum group by multiple keys in array at same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Having array:

```
[ { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  1, 'd' => 1, 'e' => 2},
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  2, 'd' => 1, 'e' => 2},
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  3, 'd' => 1, 'e' => 2},
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>  4, 'd' => 2, 'e' => 2 },
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>  5, 'd' => 2, 'e' => 2 },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  6, 'd' => 3, 'e' => 2 },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  7, 'd' => 3, 'e' => 2 },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  8, 'd' => 3, 'e' => 2 },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>  9, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 2 },
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 10, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 2 } ]
```

I want to get max of 'c', sum 'd', sum 'e' grouped by 'a' and 'b'.

So, the result should be:

```
[ { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  3, 'd' => 3, 'e' => 6},
  { 'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>  5, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 4},
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 1, 'c' =>  8, 'd' => 9, 'e' => 6},
  { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 10, 'd' => 8, 'e' => 4} ]
```

So far, I follow [How to find max value grouped by multiple keys in array of hashes?](http://How%20to%20find%20max%20value%20grouped%20by%20multiple%20keys%20in%20array%20of%20hashes?), using this code to get max of each group

```
a.group_by { |h| h.values_at("a", "b") }.map { |_, v| v.max_by { |h| h["c"] } }
```

Please guide me, get sum too. Thanks a lot.

P/s: using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.5

Comment: if my question duplicated, could SO give me the same one? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
a.group_by { |h| h.values_at("a", "b") }.map do |_, v|
  v.inject { |c, h| c.merge({ "c" => [c["c"], h["c"]].max,
                              "d" => c["d"] + h["d"],
                              "e" => c["e"] + h["e"] }) }
end
```

Comment: Anh - you could just duplicate the last tap; ex.: a.group_by { |h| h.values_at("a", "b") }.map { |_, v| v.max_by { |h| h["c"] }.tap { |h| h["d"] = v.inject(0) { |sum, h| sum + h["d"] } }.tap { |h| h["e"] = v.inject(0) { |sum, h| sum + h["e"] } } }  Edited out my comment about versions - think I was wrong.

Comment: Jonathan, Working fine in my env. Tap defined in 1.8.7 already. However, the syntax maybe difficult for beginner like me. Could you extend it to easier format? Thanks you all again.

Comment: I made a new answer with the beautified format.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Updated it to include sum of "e" and spread out a bit for clarity.

Comment: Actually, you can get the max in the inject call as well. Updated.

Comment: Max, if I want get max from additional keys ("c" and "f"). How could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As you requested in the comments, here's my comment extended into an easier format.  My edit to Max's post was rejected.

```
a.group_by { |h| h.values_at("a", "b") }.
  map { |_, v| v.max_by { |h| h["c"] }.
    tap { |h| h["d"] = v.inject(0) { |sum, h| sum + h["d"] } }.
    tap { |h| h["e"] = v.inject(0) { |sum, h| sum + h["e"] } } }
```

Comment: Jonathan, more require: get max from additional keys ("f") (max of "c" and "f"). Please teach me how to do that.